# Extracting columns from pandas dataframe without hard coding

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to extract a subset of columns from a pandas dataframe without specifying all of the columns. e.g. I have dataframe with foll. columns:
`str_ID, num_ID, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995` and I want to extract columns from `1990` onwards. How do I do that without hard coding it?

```
df.columns.values
array(['str_ID', 'num_ID', 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995], dtype=object)
```

Comment: do you know the order or the position the column in dataframe??

Comment: I only know the name of the column starting from which I want to extract columns. In this case, i want to extract all columns starting from `1990`

Comment: Something like: `df.loc[:,'1990':]`

Comment: can try this .. `df.loc[:, '1990':]`

Comment: thnks @AChampion and @Prakash. The `1990`... columns are integer types and not strings, so I get this error: `*** TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [1990] of <class 'int'>`

Comment: Slightly uglier: `df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_loc(1990):]`

Comment: I can't find anything that says you can't slice with `int` columns, so this maybe a bug, e.g. `df.loc[:,1990]` works fine but `df.loc[:,1990:]` throws `TypeError`. It's only an issue when you have mixed types across the columns, e.g. `<str>, <str>, <int>, <int>` - can't slice the ints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a conditional comprehension on the columns of the dataframe (assumes the column titles for the years are integers):

```
df[sorted(col for col in df if isinstance(col, int) and col >= 1990)]
```

This filters for integer columns greater than or equal to 1990 and returns the result in a sorted order.

Answer (score 1):

Another option if the header are strings and there are no years before 1900:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'str_ID':[4,2,4,5,5,4],
               'num_ID': [4,2,4,5,5,4],
               '1990':[4,3,1,2,2,4],
               '1991':[1,2,4,5,5,3],
               '1992':[4,3,2,2,2,4],
               '1993':[4,3,2,2,2,4]})
print df
   1990  1991  1992  1993  num_ID  str_ID
0     4     1     4     4       4       4
1     3     2     3     3       2       2
2     1     4     2     2       4       4
3     2     5     2     2       5       5
4     2     5     2     2       5       5
5     4     3     4     4       4       4

columns = [x for x in df.columns if (x>=1990 and x.isdigit())]
df = df[columns]
print df
```

Output:

```
   1990  1991  1992  1993
0     4     1     4     4
1     3     2     3     3
2     1     4     2     2
3     2     5     2     2
4     2     5     2     2
5     4     3     4     4
```

Comment: `.isdigit` only works on strings, whereas the OP's year columns are integers. Worse yet, '1800' > 1990 evaluates to True.

Comment: @Alexander You are right, thanks! my solution only works if the headers are string, and there are no years before 1900. Upvote for your right solution